# Panel page title with date field

Tags: 7, panels

I have a panel page with title set to %node:field_pub_year from substitution list. field_pub_year is a date field which is to select publication year. My problem is this is displaying whole date like '2012-01-01 00:00:00' as title. Is it possible to show only '2012' as title.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theme_preprocess_page hook

```
    // CIsSharp, 07/23/2013: For 'projects' page, only display year as title
    if (isset($variables['node'])) {
        if (isset($variables['node']->type) && $variables['node']->type == 'projects' &&
            isset($variables['node']->field_pub_year)) {
          $date = strtotime($variables['node']->field_pub_year[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);
          $year = date('Y', $date);
          $title = $year . ' Project';
          drupal_set_title($title);

          // Because breadcrumb creation executes before preprocess
          // Fix breadcrumbs title also
          $crumbs = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
          if (count($crumbs) > 0) {
             $crumbs[count($crumbs) - 1] = $title;
             drupal_set_breadcrumb($crumbs);
          }
      }
   }
```

Comment: thanks...this may be helpful to someone who have the same problem...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you opt for this instead of %node:field_pub_year? You said that works, and it seems like a much simpler solution?

Comment: I want to display only year. If I use %node:field_pub_year, it displays complete date. Eg 2012-01-01 00:00:00.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define title like %node:field_pub_year:value:custom:Y

Comment: I tried but it is now displaying no title.

Comment: you must to enable both Entity API and Entity Tokens to make it work...is this modules enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are enabled. Actually it is working with %node:field_pub_year

Comment: Try with [Panels Custom Title Tag](https://drupal.org/project/panels_custom_title_tag) module, it works with any token compatible with the page_title module...custom tokens are compatible...if doesn't work, try to use dev version of [Date](https://drupal.org/project/date) module...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed it using theme_preprocess_page.

Comment: You're welcome...can you just post here solution...

Comment: I posted the solution